# In GWT, what does the "[...].java' is removed due to invalid reference(s)" mean?

Tags: java, gwt

I have converted a GWT Eclipse based project to GWT-Maven but when I run the command

```
mvn clean gwt:compile
```

I get an awful lot of errors that specify:

```
[class name].java' is removed due to invalid reference(s):
```

My pom.xml dependencies are:

- dom4j-1.6.1
- commons-httpclient-3.1
- gwt-servlet-1.6.4
- gwt-user-1.6.4
- junit-4.3.1
- gwtext-2.0.5
- GWTx-20070605

What do these errors mean and how do I go about diagnosing the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the removed class refers to a method that is implemented as part of the GWT 
JRE emulation library :

http://library.igcar.gov.in/readit2007/tutori/tools/gwt-windows-1.4.10/doc/html/jre.html

If your software makes use of reflection it is very probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this means that something higher up in the calling chain was invalid, either because of a compile error, or because it was, or was using, a class that can't be 'compiled' by the GWT compiler.  So, if you have class A which references class B, and class B cannot be compiled, class A will be removed due to an invalid reference.